# How to get reverse geocoding to work only after getCurrentLocation?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a user location and from there display their location on a map along with specific details like country and city on the website itself but the problem is that it seems the reverse geocoding finishes before the current location is obtained.

I've tried using await but it seems to completely mess up the code

```
function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': latlng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      alert(status);
    }

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
}

function initMap() {
  var currloc = {
    lat: 37.9,
    lng: -119.4
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: currloc,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map,
    position: currloc
  });

  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latit = (Math.round(position.coords.latitude * 100)) / 100;
      var longit = (Math.round(position.coords.longitude * 100)) / 100;

      console.log("Geolocation supported");
      console.log(latit);
      console.log(longit);

      marker.setPosition({
        lat: latit,
        lng: longit
      });

      map.panTo({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Geolocation not supported");
  }

  getReverseGeocodingData(latit, longit)
}

// google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) {
//var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
//position: event.latLng,
//map: map,
//title: event.latLng.lat()+', '+event.latLng.lng()
//});
//});
```

Expected to output the details of the current location (Singapore) but outputs the default location (so it doesn't register the current loc.)

Comment: Where is `initMap` being called?

Answer (score 0):

Because both the `google.maps.Geocoder()` and `navigator.geolocation` are asynchronous they are not guaranteed to return in a particular order so you need to structure your code to operate with the success of each stage. For you, in this case, I'd say that the call to `navigator.geolocation` is the primary call - when it returns with the user location you should proceed to obtain the Geocoder response - and when the geocoder returns it's response use the callback to display the marker or pan the map or whatever..

I cobbled together a quick demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Maps: Locate user using geolocation</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            body,
            html { height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box; }
            #map { width:90%;height:90vh; margin:auto;float:none; }
            #info{display:none; padding:1rem;margin:0.25rem;border:1px solid black;background:white;}
            #info div{margin:0.5rem auto;}
            #info div:before{content:attr(data-label)":";text-transform:capitalize;font-weight:bold;color:black;margin:0 0.5rem 0 0;}
            #info div:after{content:attr(data-value);color:red;}
        </style>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                if( 'geolocation' in navigator ) {

                    let map,marker,geocoder,infoWindow;
                    let args={ enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout:Infinity, maximumAge:60000 };

                    /* Yosemite Nation Park - home of Yogi Bear */
                    let initial_location={  
                        lat:37.865067,
                        lng:-119.538338
                    };

                    /* Create the map at the default location */
                    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 20, 
                        center: initial_location,
                        disableDoubleClickZoom:true,
                        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                        mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU }
                    });


                    const addmarker=function( latlng, obj ){
                        let options={ map:map, position:latlng };
                        Object.keys( obj ).map( function( k ){ options[ k ]=obj[ k ]; } );
                        return new google.maps.Marker( options );
                    };


                    const getgeodata=function( pos,marker ){
                        geocoder.geocode( { latLng:pos },function( results, status ){
                            if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                                /* do something with the geocoder response data */
                                google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
                                    content=infoWindow.getContent();
                                    content.querySelector('[data-label="address"]').dataset.value=results[0].formatted_address;
                                    content.querySelector('[data-label="type"]').dataset.value=results[0].types.join(', ');
                                    content.querySelector('[data-label="co-ordinates"]').dataset.value=[pos.lat,pos.lng].join(', ');
                                    content.style.display='block';
                                    infoWindow.setPosition( pos );
                                    infoWindow.open( map );
                                });
                                map.setCenter( pos );
                                map.setZoom( 4 );
                            }
                        });
                    };


                    const evtSuccess=function( pos ){
                        let user_location = {
                            lat:pos.coords.latitude,
                            lng:pos.coords.longitude
                        };
                        /* invoke the Geocoder */
                        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                        /* create the infowindow and assign the hidden content which will be populated later */
                        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth:350, disableAutoPan:false });
                        infoWindow.setContent( document.getElementById('info') );

                        /* add a marker to the user's "found" location */
                        let marker = addmarker( user_location,{ title:'My location' } );

                        /* attempt to find the GeoCoder data for the user's "Found" location */
                        getgeodata.call( this, user_location, marker );
                    };


                    const evtFailure=function( err ){
                        console.info( err )
                    };

                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( evtSuccess, evtFailure, args );
                }
            }
        </script>
        <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<APIKEY>&callback=initMap' async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id='map'>loading...</div>
      <!-- content for infoWindow -->
      <div id='info'>
        <div data-label='address' data-value=''></div>
        <div data-label='type' data-value=''></div>
        <div data-label='co-ordinates' data-value=''></div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```